# Obtain current user session outside of the service in a thread safe manner

Tags: c#, servicestack, nhibernate-envers

My ServiceStack-based app uses built-in Authentication feature and runs in SelfHosted mode (`AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase`).

I'm using NHibernate with Envers for audit trailing. Envers could be provided with optional **singleton instance** which fills additional revision info. I'd like to store **current user's auth name** in the revision info.

I need to **access** current request (i.e. "**current user session**") **outside** of the **Services** code, in my singleton instance. How do I do this with ServiceStack? How to make it thread safe?

Comment: Did you get the `ThreadStatic` approach to work?

Comment: @Scott sorry for not answering so long. I've modified a bit your approach, so I've ended up with something similar to custom HttpContext. It's being hold on a ThreadStatic field, set by ServiceRunner. It seems to work, I have to conduct some tests with handling parallel connections. I hope there are no surprises like one request being processed by different threads ...

Comment: That's good you managed to get something working, I hope as you say there aren't any surprises. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use NHibernate or Envers myself, so perhaps just spitballing here. I don't think a current user session really exists outside the scope of the service. But you should be able to pass the Envers scope in. I think what you would want to do, is pass a reference to your singleton instance into service using the [AppHost IoC](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container).

In your `AppHost` setup your singleton instance, then register it with the container so it is injected into each Service request.

By doing something like:

```
container.Register(c => singletonInstance).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);
```

You would need to extend `Service` to use a custom base:

```
public class MyServiceBaseWithEnversSupport : Service
{
    public EnversSingletonInstanceType Envers { get; set; } // IoC will inject here
}
```

Then your handlers would need to use this extended custom `Service` base, so something like this: *`CustomerHandler` is just an example, your service handlers will vary*

```
public class CustomerHandler : MyServiceBaseWithEnversSupport
{
    public object Get(ListCustomers request)
    {
        // You can then access the instance in the scope of the request
        // So you now have access to the current user identity
        Envers.Username = Session.Username; // Just an example modify as required.
    }
}
```

You could have the values auto-populated, to save having to set the values in each action handler by setting up a custom [`ServiceRunner`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IServiceRunner.cs).

Create a custom `ServiceRunner`:

```cs
public class ServiceRunner<T> : ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRunner<T>
{
    public ServiceRunner(IAppHost appHost, ActionContext actionContext) : base(appHost, actionContext)
    {
    }

    public override object Execute(IRequestContext requestContext, object instance, T request)
    {
        // Check if the instance is of type MyServiceBaseWithEnversSupport
        var ms = instance as MyServiceBaseWithEnversSupport;

        // If the request is not using the MyServiceBaseWithEnversSupport, then allow it to run, as normal.
        if(ms == null)
            return base.Execute(requestContext, instance, request);

        // Access the Envers object, set using the Session Information
        ms.Envers.Username = ms.Session.Username;

        return base.Execute(requestContext, ms, request);
    }
}
```

Configure you application to use it by adding this to your `AppHost`:

```cs
public override IServiceRunner<TRequest> CreateServiceRunner<TRequest>(ActionContext actionContext)
{
    return new ServiceRunner<TRequest>(this, actionContext);
}
```

Sorry parts are a little vague with regards to the Enver's singleton object type and the correct properties or methods to call on the object to set the data, but I assume you can substitute in the appropriate values.

*As I said I am not familiar with either NHibernate or Envers, so this could be off, but it may be of some help at least regarding the ServiceStack side*

---

### Updated attempt:

I presume that for each request to your service the following happens:

- The application host creates a Service context thread for the request.
- Within the thread the user session exists
- Each request will perform some NHibernate database action.
- The database action may trigger an event handler in your envers listener. You need to populate with the username of the current request, i.e. in the scope of the current thread.

Have you considered creating a [`ThreadStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) `static` variable that is global to both ServiceStack and your Envers event handler in the listener?

```
public static class Global
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    public static string Username;
}
```

Then in ServiceStack set the value of `Username` at the point of Authentication, which will occur before your listener's handler. Then in the listener handler read the value from `Global.Username`. The value is thread safe and only exists in the scope of the request.

*Note: I assume that NHibernate/Envers runs on the request thread, and that it doesn't spawn other worker threads for each request.*

Comment: Hi, thank you for the idea. I was considering accessing somehow the instance and "manually" setting the current user for the envers listener (I consider your code "manual" way, no matter how automated it is ;) ). However I'm very afraid of it's thread-safeness. What would happen when two requests are processed simultaneously? I'm afraid that would require me to lock the "envers-listener" singleton instance for entire request processing. That doesn't sound like a good idea...

Comment: @migajek I can see your concern, can you post your singleton's code, and how you would set it? So I understand that you are telling the singleton who the user is, how does it know what records they have changed during their request? If I can understand that I think the solution would be to build a queue, that runs updating the singleton with requests that have completed, and because it is a background worker, it won't block the normal operation.

Comment: Envers is audit trailing library, so it is responsible for tracking changes in my entities. My singleton is envers listener which is responsible for assigning extra data to revision - in my case I'd like to assign current user name. So, each time the singleton's method is called by Envers, I need to know current user's name. If any entities has changed, Envers will create revision & ask for it's details in the same transaction I've created manually, thus - it will be called before the end of request processing.Its not being queued in any way, so at least the order of execution is certain

Comment: @migajek I have updated my answer. I have thought that perhaps using `[ThreadStatic]` to make the `Username` accessible to the request thread may work. Please let me know how you get on.